# CircleCi randomly disconnects from browser when running Karma specs

Tags: angular, automated-tests, circleci

I have a large program written in Angularjs and in the middle of a migration to Angular 7 (soon to be 8). We have 9000+ spec's and about 1/4 of them are Angular 7. For a while now, CircleCI would occasionally fail the entire suite with this error message:

```
HeadlessChrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
Disconnectedreconnect failed before timeout of 2000ms (transport close)
HeadlessChrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 8962 of 9075 DISCONNECTED (6 mins 29.171 secs / 6 mins 7.538 secs)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The executed spec's is somewhat random, the specs fail somewhere between 8900 and 9050.

A couple of weeks ago, it started to always fail on one branch and forcing the master branch to re-run exhibited the same bug.

All spec's execute cleanly locally using a similar build, same Headless Chrome version, same test runner. The main difference is that the reporter is different (we use the dots reporter on CircleCI and more of a summary locally).

I have searched CircleCI's "knowledge base" for "Disconnect" and "Flakiness" with no useable results. Most of the search results in Google that come up regarding this are from ancient versions of things... HeadlessChrome, Karma, Jasmine, etc. I have tried, for example, setting up a custom "HeadlessChrome" with no sandbox, but to no avail.

What is the problem and do you have any suggestions on how to go about diagnosing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customer support has gotten back to me and informed me that I have used all of the available memory for a process.  At this time, Circle Ci only allows containers to use up to 4GB of RAM, with the Container OS, the Angular and angularjs frameworks, the Jasmine and Karma library, and all of our production and test code, we ran out of space.

Apparently, we had been hovering around 4GB of memory for a while, so we got intermittent failures, but my new branch finally pushed it all the way over. We worked hard to ensure there were no memory leaks, but at some point, you just have too much code.

So my solution is to split the tests. We had several lazy loaded modules, but for now, our best split is on Angular and angularjs (because it allowed for better conversion setup). So in my jasmine configuration, when picking files to include, I updated the second line of this:

```
_requireContext(require.context('../lib/fixtures', true, /\.js$/););
_requireContext(require.context('./app', true, /\.spec\.[j|t]s$/));

function _requireContext(context: any) {
  context.keys().forEach((path: string) => {
    try {
      context(path);
    } catch (err) {
      /* tslint:disable */
      console.error(`[ERROR] REQUIRING FILE: ${path}`);
      console.error(err);
      /* tslint:enable */
      throw err;
    }
  });
}
```

To either include or exclude typescript/javascript files and I was good to go. It looked a bit like this:

```
_requireContext(require.context('./app', true, /\.spec\.js$/));
```

vs

```
_requireContext(require.context('./app', true, /\.spec\.ts$/));
```

It increases complication (now I basically have two test suites), but it worked and overall my specs run faster on CircleCI as well.

One last note - I had zero issues on my development computer - obviously I have more than 4GB of RAM, the only way to see how much RAM your test suite is using on CircleCI is to ask them directly. This stat is nowhere you can find on the site.

Comment: One huge advantage that I found for the way I split my files is that my dependencies and patterns changed in the conversion. I was able to eliminate many helper and matcher files from my new Angular specs, and I was able to more easily identify where I used these old helpers in these specs and replace them.